# Custom binding that auto-attaches to every bound element?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

Is there anyway to add a "global" custom binding? For instance, I want a binding to fire for every element that is bound, without having to add the binding to the `data-bind` attribute. Think of it as an initializer that fires sometime during the data-binding process.

What I really want to do is this: when a new model is added to an `observableArray`, I want to auto-focus on the new model's first `input` so the user can begin typing right away. I didn't think this would work with any of the existing bindings.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.attach = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        valueAccessor().boundElements.push(element);
    }
};
```

That works, but I'd rather not have to do `data-bind="attach: $data"` on every bound element. Is there any way to tell KO to always use the `attach` binding whenever there is another binding on an element.

**Note:** After writing this I think I've decided to go with the manual method anyway, but I'd still like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is specifically about how to focus a view's first `input` when a new model is added, because the technique I propose for doing this is quite different from yours.

I had this same requirement in a recent project and basically solved it by including an observable in my view model called `firstHasFocus`. Whenever that view model was to become active, like when switching "tabs", I'd set `firstHasFocus` to `true`. In the view, the first `input` is bound to that observable using `hasfocus`.

Here's an example from my code that responds to the "Next" button in a wizard-type interface. It switches to the next step, and if that's currently the last available step, it focuses the first input.

```
this.goNext = function() {
    if (this.isNextAvailable()) {
        var newIndex = this.currentStepIndex() + 1;
        this.setCurrentStep(this.steps()[newIndex], newIndex);
        if (!this.isNextAvailable()) {
            this.currentStep().firstHasFocus(true);
        }
    }
};
```

To make sure that `firstHasFocus(true)` always updates the binding, it's defined to always notify:

```
this.firstHasFocus = ko.observable(false).extend({notify: 'always'});
```

Each step has a corresponding view that can include a binding to `firstHasFocus`.

```
<h1>Select the Station Info Columns</h1>
<form>
    <label for="stationColumn">Station Name</label>
    <select id="stationColumn" name="stationColumn" data-bind="
                    options: data.headerVarNames, optionsCaption: '----',
                    value: data.stationHeaderName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
                    setfocus: firstHasFocus"></select>
    <label for="siteColumn">Site Name</label>
    <select id="siteColumn" name="siteColumn" data-bind="
                    options: data.headerVarNames, optionsCaption: '----',
                    value: data.siteNameHeaderName"></select>
...
```

I'm using a custom binding, `setfocus`, instead of the standard `hasfocus` because don't ever want `blur` to be called. Here's my `setfocus` binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.setfocus = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var modelValue = valueAccessor();
        if (!ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
            throw new Error('setfocus must be used with a writable observable');
        }
        var writeValue = function(event) {
            var modelValue = valueAccessor(),
                valueToWrite = element.ownerDocument.activeElement === element;
            if (event.type == 'focusin' && !valueToWrite)
                element.focus();
            else if (valueToWrite != modelValue())
                modelValue(valueToWrite);
        };
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "focus", writeValue);
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "focusin", writeValue); // For IE
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "blur",  writeValue);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor()();   // access and unwrap observable
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (value && element.offsetWidth && element.offsetHeight && document.activeElement && document.activeElement != element) {
                element.focus();
                ko.utils.triggerEvent(element, "focusin"); // For IE, which doesn't reliably fire "focus" or "blur" events synchronously
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally your view model shouldn't need access to the DOM elements (that's what bindings are for). But there is a way to do this, and it's called a custom binding provider. This isn't officially documented, but it's described is some detail on [Ryan Niemeyer's blog](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html).

So here's one way you could modify the binding provider to add this behavior:

```
var origNodeHasBindings = ko.bindingProvider.instance.nodeHasBindings,
    origGetBindings = ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindings;

ko.bindingProvider.instance.nodeHasBindings = function(node) {
    return (node.nodeType === 1) || origNodeHasBindings(node);
};
ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindings = function(node, bindingContext) {
    var bindings = origGetBindings.call(this, node, bindingContext) || {};
    bindings.attach = bindingContext.$data;
    return bindings;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? E.g. when a new model is added to an `observableArray`, I want to auto-focus on the model's first `input` so the user can begin typing right away. I didn't think this would work with any of the existing bindings.

Comment: Can you add that to your question? Then I can add a different answer about it.

Comment: Yep, I didn't forget - just need to find time to read/try this! ;-)